# Server ip is displayed insted of client ip in sentry logback

Tags: logback, sentry

Server ip is displayed instead of client ip in Sentry.

sentry raven version : raven-logback:7.8.5

In the ngnix i have set the following headrs as

```
proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Note: Is there any way that we can get the client ip in sentry tags ?